# Import a specific part from natural library (webpack)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am using the npm [natural](https://www.npmjs.com/package/natural) library for tokenization and only use it in one line, as shown below:

```
let token = natural.StemmerJa.prototype.tokenizeAndStem(searchWord, true);
```

However, I wasn't sure how to import it in webpack since tokenizeAndStem seems like a method of the natural object.

I'm importing it like this:

```
import natural from "natural";
```

Is there any way I can just get StemmerJa's tokenizeAndStem? This is because my current app builds the whole library and it's making load times quite slow.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to import the stemmer directly:

```
import StemmerJa from "natural/lib/natural/stemmers/stemmer_ja";
```

(it is in: `node_modules/natural/lib/natural/stemmers/stemmer_ja.js`).

I tested this approach with the following code which yields the 16kb bundle (importing whole `natural` lib gives about 7.8Mb bundle):

```
import PorterStemmer from "natural/lib/natural/stemmers/porter_stemmer";

PorterStemmer.attach();
console.log("i am waking up to the sounds of chainsaws".tokenizeAndStem());
console.log("chainsaws".stem());
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That library was making my website load really slow (~70 on performance on lighthouse but now I get a 98 when doing the lighthouse audit!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax:

```
import {StemmerJa} from 'natural';
```

Try playing with the imports to see what works.

Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_a_single_export_from_a_module